# How to pass an object as a prop in React using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

I am trying to learn typescript and to be quite honest I am having a hell of a time wrapping my head around this. I understand that this question has been asked COUNTLESS times before but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to translate the answers that I'm reading to my own code. Something which doesn't help is a lot of the answers I seem to find use a different syntax to write components than I have been using. Anyways any help is GREATLY appreciated because I am completely lost here. I have literally only two files, App.tsx and DisplayPerson.tsx

Inside my App.tsx file I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DisplayPerson from './components/DisplayPerson';

export interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function App() {
    const person1: Person = {
        firstName: 'fname',
        lastName: 'lname',
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <DisplayPerson person={person1} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And inside my DisplayPerson.tsx file I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Person } from '../App';

export default function DisplayPerson({ person }: Person) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>person.firstName</h1>
            <h1>person.lastName</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In DisplayPerson.tsx I have an error which says "Property 'person' does not exist on type 'Person'". I tried to fix this by changing my Person interface to:

```
export interface Person {
    person : {
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
    }
}
```

And the declaration of my person1 const to this:

```
const person1: Person = {
        person: {
            firstName: 'fname',
            lastName: 'lname',
        },
    };
```

Which did solve the error in DisplayPerson.tsx, however I now have an error in App.tsx which says "Type 'Person' is missing the following properties from type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string;}': firstName, lastName. The expected type comes from property 'person' which was declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Person"

This is when I tried googling my issue and frankly I just cannot figure out what's wrong even without googling. Any help is greatly appreciated and if you could also explain why what I've done does not work I would love that a lot.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to correct your props part. So your `DisplayPerson.tsx` file will be like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Person } from '../App';

interface IProps {
   person: Person
}
export default function DisplayPerson({ person }: IProps) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{person.firstName}</h1>
            <h1>{person.lastName}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

##### Update:

In React, the structure is like below for Functional component

```
function DisplayPerson(props) {}
```

as you see here `props` is a parameter that is of type `object`. so you need to pass an `object`. Now you want a `person` as a `key` inside that object which is Object deconstruction.
That's why it has to be done like #1 from the answer of Nathan.
You can refer this: https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring

Comment: Thank you!! This did work and thanks for the update to your answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a couple small issues in `DisplayPerson.tsx`. I've fixed them in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-snyder-s5bmt?file=/src/App.tsx

`DisplayPerson.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Person } from '../App';

export default function DisplayPerson({ person }: { person: Person }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{person.firstName}</h1>
            <h1>{person.lastName}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

1. Your prop type is incorrect. Instead of `{ person }: Person` you should have `{ person }: { person: Person }`.
2. You should wrap `person.firstName` and `person.lastName` with `{}`

To elaborate on #1: The props passed into `DisplayPerson` is an object where the key is the prop name and the value is whatever's passed in. Therefore, the type of the props object isn't `Person` but rather an object with key `person` and a value of type `Person`.

Comment: Thank you this did work! Could you please explain why I need to do #1? What exactly does "{person: Person}" do after already saying {person}?

Comment: I have given you an update on your question on my answer. As it's not much readable here. Please have a look at that.

Comment: Thank you Chirag. I appreciate the link and your answer in the thread as well

Answer (score 3):

I have found the issue, you are not passing the parameters as props. You have to do it, I have fixed it:

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import DisplayPerson from './components/DisplayPerson';

export interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function App() {
    const person1: Person = {
        firstName: 'fname',
        lastName: 'lname',
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <DisplayPerson person={person1} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

DisplayPerson.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Person } from '../App';

export default function DisplayPerson(props:{person:Person}) {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.person.firstName}</h1>
            <h1>{props.person.lastName}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```